# Speed Issues with MySQL query View

Tags: mysql

I use databases all of the time within various solutions, but never really design them. Therefore, I'm pretty new to the finer points of SQL. I have a database that has many tables, but 2 main ones:
Item - references lots of other tables for data that doesn't change with revisions and
Entry - references lots of other tables for data that does change with revisions
Each item will therefore have 1 or more revision (with all associated data).

I want to select all data for all revisions (and consequently items) with a view. I've structured a single query as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW Single_Query
AS
SELECT  i.REF_CODE AS REF
gp.GROUP_NAME AS Group
v.VERSION_NUMBER AS Version
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cy.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Country
ey.PUB_DATE AS Published
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ct.CONTRIBUTOR_NAME) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Author
i.ISBN_CODE AS ISBN
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cn.COMPONENT_NUMBER, _utf8', ',cn.COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION) SEPARATOR '; ') AS Contents
ey.NOTES AS Notes
i.PRICE AS Price
cl.COLOUR_DESCRIPTION AS Colour
FROM entry AS ey
JOIN item AS i ON ey.ITEM_ID = i.ITEM_ID
JOIN group AS gp ON i.GROUP_ID = gp.GROUP_ID
JOIN version AS v ON ey.VERSION_ID = v.VERSION_ID
JOIN link_country_item AS lci ON i.ITEM_ID = lci.ITEM_ID
JOIN country AS cy ON lci.COUNTRY_ID = cy.COUNTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN link_entry_contributor AS lec ON ey.ENTRY_ID = lec.ENTRY_ID
LEFT JOIN contributor AS ct ON lec.CONTRIBUTOR_ID = ct.CONTRIBUTOR_ID
JOIN contents AS cn ON i.ITEM_ID = cn.ITEM_ID
JOIN colour AS cl ON ey.COLOUR_ID = cl.COLOUR_ID
GROUP BY REF_CODE, VERSION_NUMBER
```

This takes about 29 seconds to complete, with only a few entries! However, if I run a script to create temporary tables for the item data (and all referenced data) and the entry data (and all referenced data), then select the whole lot from the 2 temporary tables with a single JOIN on ITEM_ID, then it takes less than half a second to complete.

Note that there are lots of other referenced tables (I've omitted them for clarity).

If it helps, the item table references the group, setting (through the many-many link_country_item table) and contents tables.

The entry table references the version, contributor (through the many-many link_entry_contributor table) and colour tables.

The problem is that I don't really want to use temporary tables all of the time as I can't use them in a view (or at least I haven't found out how). Is there a more elegant way of splitting the SQL in a View so that it runs faster in this scenario?

Many Thanks in advance

Iain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've slightly restructured the querying order, and see your comment about the REF_CODE.  So you are correct, the original index answer wouldn't cover for you.  However, with the item table in the primary position, if that has an index on (REF_CODE, ITEM_ID) should help the performance, as you are STARTING with the table, and a corresponding index for your GROUP BY clause.

```
CREATE VIEW Single_Query
AS
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      i.REF_CODE AS REF
      gp.GROUP_NAME AS Group
      v.VERSION_NUMBER AS Version
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(cy.COUNTRY_DESCRIPTION) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Country
      ey.PUB_DATE AS Published
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(ct.CONTRIBUTOR_NAME) SEPARATOR ', ') AS Author
      i.ISBN_CODE AS ISBN
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(cn.COMPONENT_NUMBER, _utf8', ',cn.COMPONENT_DESCRIPTION) SEPARATOR '; ') AS Contents
      ey.NOTES AS Notes
      i.PRICE AS Price
      cl.COLOUR_DESCRIPTION AS Colour
   FROM 
      item AS i 
         JOIN entry ey
            ON i.ITEM_ID = ey.ITEM_ID
            JOIN version AS v  
               ON ey.VERSION_ID = v.VERSION_ID
            JOIN colour AS cl 
               ON ey.COLOUR_ID = cl.COLOUR_ID
            LEFT JOIN link_entry_contributor AS lec 
               ON ey.ENTRY_ID = lec.ENTRY_ID
               LEFT JOIN contributor AS ct 
                  ON lec.CONTRIBUTOR_ID = ct.CONTRIBUTOR_ID
         JOIN group AS gp 
            ON i.GROUP_ID = gp.GROUP_ID
         JOIN link_country_item AS lci 
            ON i.ITEM_ID = lci.ITEM_ID
            JOIN country AS cy 
               ON lci.COUNTRY_ID = cy.COUNTRY_ID
         JOIN contents AS cn 
            ON i.ITEM_ID = cn.ITEM_ID
   GROUP BY 
      REF_CODE, 
      VERSION_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply DRapp. Appreciate you taking the time. I'm not sure I can make an index in the 'Entry' table on REF_CODE and VERSION_ID as REF_CODE is not linked to the 'Entry' table directly - it links to the 'Item' table, and is in turn referenced via the 'Entry/Item' link during the view execution. Unless I've misunderstood the answer...

Comment: @user2001184, revised answer.

Comment: That's superb! I put the amendments in place and the query time has now gone down from 29 seconds to virtually instantaneous. Many thanks for all of your help on this one. I'll definitely remember to apply this kind of structure in future. :-)